# tutorial of create a website to connect to another machine via SSH?

Tags: ssh, web

Is there any tutorial or instruction about how to implement SSH connection when creating a webpage?
Which means I could connect to other machines via SSH in this webpage. 
Has no clue on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

And an HTML5 web-based terminal emulator and SSH client, `GateOne`, to do what you want : https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne